# What are the effects of stacking the Extraordinary Artisan feat with itself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, eberron

Extraordinary Artisan feat (ECS) as indicated in the table (p49, feat on 53) indicates that it stacks with itself.

What are the mathematical effects of taking this feat multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The <sup>2</sup> in the table is an error, and is removed by errata

None of Exceptional Artisan, Extraordinary Artisan, or Legendary Artisan is allowed to be taken more than once, nor do they stack with one another if you somehow get them more than once. The <sup>2</sup> indicator in the Item Creation Feats table for these feats is incorrect, does not match the text of the feats themselves, and was removed by errata:

> #### Page 49: Feats Table—Item Creation Feats
>
> Remove the superscript “2” after the feats Exceptional Artisan, Extraordinary Artisan, and Legendary Artisan. Each feat can be taken once only, not multiple times.

<sup>([*Eberron Campaign Setting* errata](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101183021/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/ECSerrata_02062006.zip))</sup>

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I didn't have the errata handy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing (I don't normally do Eberron) is that it reduces the base price by 25% (for the purposes of determining raw material costs only) in crafting. If it does indeed stack (I can't see exactly where it says that), then you would multiply the base price by 0.75^x, where x is the number of times you've taken the feat, then determine the raw material cost from that reduced base cost.

But again this reduction in base cost is only for determining raw material costs. In all other respects, the base cost is unchanged.